# ¿Cómo pasar un valor desde el template a la vista en django?

Tags: django

Alguien puede ayudarme estoy tratando de pasar un valor que adquiere mi template al ejecutarse el modelo grupos, para que muestre los empleados que tiene cada grupo, sin pasar los parámetros por url, ya que se muestran dentro del mismo template, es decir, algo de este tipo:

```
{% for grupo in grupos %}
    {{grupo.nombre}}
    {% for empleado in empleados with grupo.id_grupo %}
        {{ empleado.nombre }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Editado, agrego modelos de empleado, empleado_por_grupos, grupos

```
class Empleados(models.Model):
id_empleado = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
nickname = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
telefono = models.CharField(max_length=15)

def __str__(self):
    return '{} {} {}'.format(self.nickname, self.nombre, self.telefono)

class EmpleadosPorGrupos(models.Model):
   id_empleado = models.ForeignKey(Empleados, models.DO_NOTHING,
                                db_column='id_empleado', primary_key=True)
   id_grupo = models.ForeignKey('Grupos', models.DO_NOTHING,
                             db_column='id_grupo')

class Grupos(models.Model):
 id_grupo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 nombre = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
 jefe_grupo = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 tipo_grupo = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

 def __str__(self):
    return '{} {} {}'.format(self.id_grupo, self.nombre, self.tipo_grupo)
```

El emplados with grupo.id_grupo no es correcto lo escribi para ejemplificar un poco mejor lo que quiero hacer.
Nota: la base de datos no puede ser modificada.

Comment: Sería bueno si agregarás tu modelo de empleado y de grupo, para saber como lo relacionas en la base de datos y poder ayudarte, además quería saber si actualmente tienes algún error en tu código?

Comment: @GermanAlzate, listo agregue los modelos espero puedas ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes algunas confusiones y redundancias en cuanto a como tienes los modelos escritos y como Django crea las bases de datos, para intentar ayudarte, te daré un ejemplo de cosas que podrías hacer:

Como la base de datos no puede ser modificada, debes de saber que Django, al no tener las relaciones directas en un modelo, el te proporciona una propiedad para que tu obtengas las relaciones inversas, esta propiedad puede ser cambiada al momento de crear tus modelos, por medio del atributo `related_name`, o por defecto, usa el nombre del modelo seguido del sufijo `_set`, es decir, `modelname_set`, esto, solo para el caso de relaciones `ManyToMany` o `ForeignKey`, cuando hablamos de relaciones inversas, o indirectas. De tal modo que quedaría así tu consulta:

```
{% for grupo in grupos %}
  {{ grupo.nombre }}
  {% for itermedio in grupo.empleadosporgrupo_set.all %}
    {{ intermedio.id_empleado.nombre }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Como ves, cuando obtengo un objeto del tipo `Grupos` puedo acceder a su relación inversa con la tabla `EmpleadosPorGrupos` por medio del atributo `empleadosporgrupos_set`, de la forma: `grupo.empleadosporgrupos_set`, donde `grupo` es una instancia de `Grupos`, y retorna un QuerySet con los `EmpleadosPorGrupos` que han sido creados con el grupo actual, es lo mismo que hacer esto:

```
grupo = Grupos.objects.first()
intermedio = EmpleadosPorGrupos.objects.filter(id_grupo=grupo)
```

Para sacar cada empleado, debes recorrer `intermedio` y obtener el atributo `id_empleado` que retornará una instancia del objeto `Empleados`.

Cualquier pregunta, comenta, fuera mucho mas sencillo explicar, si no tuvieras tantos enredos con los nombres, y como no puedes hacer modificaciones a la base de datos, no vale decirte como hacerlo más optimo.

Comment: Gracias tu método es muy bueno, me genera los objetos que deben ir en cada grupo pero tengo el problema de que  los muestra vacíos. @German Alzate

Comment: Ya lo resolví, quite la etiqueta with, no se porque me arrojaba los objetos vacíos y mejor hice la referencia directa, es decir, 'intermedio.id_empleado.nombre'

Comment: @EmmanuelLanderoDelAngel si la respuesta ayudó a solucionar tu pregunta, no olvides marcarla como resuelta, para así cerrar esta pregunta